# Get data from AJAX before loading AngularJS ap

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-upgrade

We are preparing for upgrading our AngularJS app and refactoring for that. Currently we are running into an architectural issue:

Our app currently loads JSON through a jQuery AJAX call, this sets up all of the data and then bootstraps the app.

We need to move the AJAX call to Angular however, so that we can bootstrap the app without waiting for the AJAX to return (which is necessary for the upgrade)

```
$.get('/ajax/init').done(function (initData) {
  walletApp.run([
    'SomeService', function (someService) {
      // ...
    },
  ]);

  walletApp.config([
    'SomeProvider', function (someProvider) {
      // ...
    },
  ]);

  walletApp
    .factory('navInfo', function () {
      return initData.navInfo;
    })
    .factory('userInfo', function () {
      return initData.userInfo;
    });

  // ETC

  // Below is the important line
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['walletApp']);
});
```

I've been trying something along the lines of the below, where the `initService` gets the JSON feed and then assigns all of the data

```
angular.module('walletApp')
  .run([
    'InitService', function (initService) {
      initService.get();
    },
  ]);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['walletApp']);
```

But this results in a bunch of issues.

How do we properly load our AngularJS app, that requires data from AJAX to operate?

Comment: Are you using `$http` and making the request ? If my understanding is correct then you want to load `JSON` data before loading the site . Please confirm

Comment: Hi @ShashankVivek, am using `this.$http.get<any>(url, {params: params})`.
Yes the AJAX data is necessary for setting up the factories and other data.

Comment: check my answer , is this what you are looking for ? or can you make load the site and then setup the data while showing spinner till the call is complete? Let me know your feedback so that I can provide better solution

Comment: A spinner would be fine while the AJAX loads, as long as we can call `angular.bootstrap` without depending on an AJAX call to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, as per my understanding, You need json data before anything else of the UI loads (since it's a data which is required before the site even loads itself).

So, you can't make `http` on config phase and if you call in `run` phase, you have to wait till the main `http` call is made(Lets call it `/site_data/`).

1. Don't use `ng-app` in index.html
2. In `app.js` file

   ```
   (function() {

   var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
   var $http = initInjector.get('$http');
   $http.get('/site_data/',{headers: {'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'}}).then(
       function (response) {
           angular.module('walletApp.info', []).constant('SITE_CONF_DATA', response.data);

           angular.element(document).ready(function() {
               angular.bootstrap(document, ['walletApp']); //<--  manual bootstrapping of `ng-app`
           });
       }
     );
   })();

   var app = angular.module('walletApp',['walletApp.info']);
   app.config(function(SITE_CONF_DATA){
      // Bingo, you have the data
   })

   app.run().....

   app.controller...

   app.factory.....
   ```

This approach has a drawback that your site will be loaded once the `http` call is resolved.

### Update

As per the comments, you are trying to build a hybrid application, so [take a look at this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajc-angular-upgrade-di-error-qwkqmv?file=app%2Fangularjs.module.ts).

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // Ensure AngularJS is only bootstrapped once.
    if (!angularJsBootstrapped) {
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').delay(5000).subscribe(res => {
        angular.module('data',[]).constant('DATA',res);
        this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [module.name]);
        setUpLocationSync(this.upgrade);
        angularJsBootstrapped = true;
      })
    }
  }
```

I have created a `constant` by creating a module after `http` is resolved and then I manually bootstrapped `angularJS` module.

`angular.module('data',[]).constant('DATA',res);`

Something like this might be helpful for the situation that you are describing.

Comment: Thanks! However we can't use this solution as `angular.bootstrap` is called inside the callback of the AJAX request. We are busy with an Angular upgrade to version `6` and the bootstrapping of the app needs to happen from the Angular 6 code. So it doesn't know if the AJAX has completed. This solution is basically the same as I already have, but using AngularJS instead of jQuery for loading the data.

Comment: you are planning to call `angularjs` code from `angular 6` code ?

Comment: https://v6.angular.io/guide/upgrade#bootstrapping-hybrid-applications - "this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp'], { strictDi: true });". When upgrading through a hybrid app, AngularJS gets bootstrapped through Angular

Comment: @Richard :Thanks for this awesome question. I have comeup with a solution and I have provided it as a demo . Let me know if it can an answer for you now. :)

Comment: @Richard: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Not yet, we are currently looking at other solutions here, we will probably be injecting the JSON directly into the HTML, so we don't need to fetch it on page load. Thanks for following up!